# Unknown warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone World and while I am building my app, I am getting this unknown warning. I have tried a lot to overcome this warning but not able to understand what type of warning is this.

`ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/lib' following -L not found**`

Please suggest me the appropriate way to overcome this.Thank You

Comment: Can you post the code where this warning appears?

Comment: @Raj More: Its a linker warning, so there is most likely no specific code line that fails